# How to mount drive? Getting "No such device"

Tags: mount

```
root@Fort-Kickass:/tmp # parted -l
Model: ATA WDC WD140EDGZ-11 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 14.0TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
1      1049kB  135MB   134MB                                      msftres
2      135MB   14.0TB  14.0TB  ntfs         Basic data partition


root@Fort-Kickass:/tmp # ll /dev/sda*
brw-rw----    1 root     root        8,   0 Dec 23 20:47 /dev/sda
brw-rw----    1 root     root        8,   1 Dec 23 20:47 /dev/sda1
brw-rw----    1 root     root        8,   2 Dec 23 20:47 /dev/sda2

root@Fort-Kickass:/tmp # ll
total 0
drwxrwxrwt    4 root     root         120 Dec 23 21:15 ./
drwxr-xr-x   20 root     root         520 Dec 23 20:44 ../
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          40 Dec 23 21:15 hdd/
root@Fort-Kickass:/tmp # ll hdd/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          40 Dec 23 21:15 ./
drwxrwxrwt    4 root     root         120 Dec 23 21:15 ../

root@Fort-Kickass:/tmp # mount -t ntfs /dev/sda2 /tmp/hdd/
mount: mounting /dev/sda2 on /tmp/hdd/ failed: No such device
```

If I try and mount sda, sda1, or sda1 it says no such device.   What am I missing here?

Comment: Add `--verbose` to the command.  Maybe that will shed more light on the problem.

Comment: Dheck `dmesg | tail -20`, perhaps there is a more verbose error message from the mount attempt.

Comment: (Sorry, typo in the previous comment: Dheck = Check.) If the drive worked for just enough time to be detected, and then failed, that might explain the "no such device" error. In that case, you might find I/O error messages at the end of the `dmesg` listing.